# extjs: How to reduce space between multiple checkbox

Tags: forms, extjs

I am using checkboxgroup in my extjs file, but the spacing between 2 checkbox is too high. I need to reduce it. Please[image] suggest changes.

[image: Image for checkbox]

Comment: paste your html and css please

Answer (score 0):

Its Solved,

I just added `columns: [50, 100],`